# Contour Plot of system of differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear

I am trying to find the fixed points and plot the nullcline/contourplot for the system below, but I get conditional cases

$$\frac{d\theta_1}{dt}= K sin(\theta_1 - \theta_2) - sin(\theta_1)$$
$$\frac{d\theta_2}{dt}= K sin(\theta_2 - \theta_1) - sin(\theta_2)$$

I get conditional cases when I try to use NSolve[] to find the fixed points and a very weird contour plot that I don't expect. I know that the system goes under a super critical pitchfork bifurcation at $K = \frac {1}{2}$ I noticed this after I was able to plot the phase portrait of the system

So, there are 3 fixed points in total.

Any help in finding the fixed points and plotting the contour plot will be appreciated. Below is my attempt

```
Solve[{Sin[x - y] - Sin[x] == 0, Sin[y - x] - Sin[y] == 0}, {x, y}]
ContourPlot[{Sin[x - y] - Sin[x] == 0, 
             Sin[y - x] - Sin[y] == 0}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
f[x_, y_, k_] := k Sin[x - y] - Sin[x]; 
g[x_, y_, k_] := k Sin[y - x] - Sin[y];
StreamPlot[{f[x, y, .1], 
           g[x, y, .1]}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
           VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.9, None}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, 
           y}]
StreamPlot[{f[x, y, 1], 
           g[x, y, 1]}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
           VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.9, None}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, 
           y}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are infinitely many equilibria, which `Solve` returns in parametrized form, with parameter `C[1]` allowed to range over the integers.  To get a finite number, put constraints on `x` and `y` to define a finite domain (e.g., `0 <= x < 2 Pi` and so forth).

Comment: The "nullclines" of the `ContourPlot` correspond to the vertical and horizontal tangents to the stream lines in the last `StreamPlot`.  They are consistent, even if they are not what your expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, there are infinitely many equilibria, which `Solve[]` returns in parametrized form, with parameter `C[1]` allowed to range over the integers. To get a finite number, put constraints on `x` and `y` to define a finite domain (e.g., `-Pi < x < Pi` and so forth to accord with the plots).  We can put the elements together in a single plot that makes a nice illustration of the flow of the phase field.

```
cs = {Directive[Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[1], Hue[0.9]],  (* contour styles *)
      Directive[Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[1], Hue[0.1]]};
legend = Style[LineLegend[Append[cs, Red],                (* legend *)
   {RawBoxes@RowBox[{"\[Piecewise]",
       GridBox[{{ToBoxes[\[DifferentialD]x == 0]}, {"Vertical Tangent"}}]}],
    RawBoxes@RowBox[{"\[Piecewise]",
       GridBox[{{ToBoxes[\[DifferentialD]y == 0]}, {"Horizontal Tangent"}}]}],
    RawBoxes@RowBox[{"\[Piecewise]",
       GridBox[{{ToBoxes[\[DifferentialD]x == \[DifferentialD]y == 0]}, {"Equilibria"}}]}]
    },
   Joined -> {True, True, False}], GridBoxOptions -> {ColumnAlignments -> Left}];

f[x_, y_, k_] := k Sin[x - y] - Sin[x];
g[x_, y_, k_] := k Sin[y - x] - Sin[y];
pts = Solve[{f[x, y, 1] == 0, g[x, y, 1] == 0, -π < x < π, -π < y < π}, {x, y}];
nc = ContourPlot[{f[x, y, 1] == 0, g[x, y, 1] == 0},
   {x, -π, π}, {y, -π, π}, ContourStyle -> cs];
sp = StreamPlot[{f[x, y, 1], g[x, y, 1]},
   {x, -π, π}, {y, -π, π}, VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.9, None}];

Legended[
 Show[
  nc, sp, Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[{x, y} /. pts]}],
  FrameLabel -> {x, y}],
 legend
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lo for the clarification!

Comment: @Rumman You're welcome.